# Cannot Access UrbanCode Deploy DB Jar File on Kubernetes

Tags: urbancode, websphere

UrbanCode Deploy Pods not able to access the ext storage to use the JDBC Mysql Jar file.

`ls: cannot access /opt/ibm-ucd/server/ext_lib/*.jar: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

UrbanCode Deploy uses a non-root user `1001` and group `1001` pod to access the storage. Make sure that the storage has the correct `chmod/chown` permissions to allow pod Read/Write access.